# XSLT3 Issue with Lookup Value | Streaming

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

I have a merged report data(data comes from two sources)as an input file and I needed to lookup a value based on a key. Currently my code is returning incorrectly looking up values. Since the size of the input data is expected to be large, I would like to use streaming for better performance.

Here is my input xml

1. Element `Number'`is the key to lookup. `Xpath is` 'Batch/Workers/Number`
2. Lookup `Phone` element based on `Number' . Xpath is`MergedOutput/Data/Row/Phone`

Sample Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<MergedOutput>
    <Data>
        <Row>
            <Employee_Batch_Id>12567</Employee_Batch_Id>
            <Phone>FirstEmp8013457896</Phone>
            <Assignment_Id>5046150263</Assignment_Id>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Employee_Batch_Id>12568</Employee_Batch_Id>
            <Phone>SecondEmp7853457896</Phone>
            <Assignment_Id>5046150263</Assignment_Id>
        </Row>
    </Data>
    <Batch>
        <Workers>
            <Number>12567</Number>
            <Contact>Work7864532890</Contact>
        </Workers>
        <Workers>
            <Number>12568</Number>
            <Contact>Work6782340167</Contact>
        </Workers>
    </Batch>
</MergedOutput>
```

Current XSLT3 code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"          
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs r1 r2 map"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="FirstReportLookupValuePhone" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Phone/text()" select="."/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="EmployeeIDLookup" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Employee_Batch_Id/text()" select="map:put($value, string(.), accumulator-before('FirstReportLookupValuePhone'))"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>    
        <xsl:template match="Batch">
            <Workers>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Workers"/>
            </Workers>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Workers">
        <xsl:variable name="vWorkers" select="copy-of()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vMappedWorker" select="accumulator-after('EmployeeIDLookup')( normalize-space($vWorkers/Number))"/>
        <Worker>
        <WorkerID><xsl:value-of select="$vWorkers/Number"/></WorkerID>
        <Work_Contact_Number><xsl:value-of select="$vWorkers/Contact"/></Work_Contact_Number>
        <Home_Contact_Number><xsl:value-of select="$vMappedWorker"/></Home_Contact_Number>
        </Worker>

    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerID>12567</WorkerID>
        <Work_Contact_Number>Work7864532890</Work_Contact_Number>
        <Home_Contact_Number/> <!-- Value is empty, Expected value is FirstEmp8013457896 -->
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <WorkerID>12568</WorkerID>
        <Work_Contact_Number>Work6782340167</Work_Contact_Number>
        <Home_Contact_Number>FirstEmp8013457896</Home_Contact_Number> <!-- Incorrect Value, Expected value is SecondEmp7853457896 -->
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
   <Worker>
      <WorkerID>12567</WorkerID>
      <Work_Contact_Number>Work7864532890</Work_Contact_Number>
      <Home_Contact_Number>FirstEmp8013457896</Home_Contact_Number>
   </Worker>
   <Worker>
      <WorkerID>12568</WorkerID>
      <Work_Contact_Number>Work6782340167</Work_Contact_Number>
      <Home_Contact_Number>SecondEmp7853457896</Home_Contact_Number>
   </Worker>
</Workers>
```

Please could someone help me figure out how could i get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the accumulator matching `Employee_Batch_ID` tries to use the accumulator value for Phone; but because the `Employee_Batch_ID` appears before the `Phone` element, the `Phone` accumulator value isn't available yet.

I think you have to reverse the logic: when you encounter an `Employee_Batch_ID/text()`, save the ID value as a string in accumulator A; when you encounter a `Phone/text()`, add an ID=phone entry to a map held in Accumulator B.

Comment: Thanks@Michael Kay. `<Home_Contact_Number/>` is empty when i tried your suggestion as below. 
    `<xsl:accumulator name="EmployeeIDLookup" as="xs:string" initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Employee_Batch_Id/text()" select="."/>
    </xsl:accumulator>`  `<xsl:accumulator name="FirstReportLookupValuePhone" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Phone/text()" select="map:put($value, string(.), accumulator-before('EmployeeIDLookup'))"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>'

Comment: I have tried reversing the logic and but doesn't seem to be working as `<Home_Contact_Number/>` is not returning value at all. Could you please let me know if anything else that i can do to make it to work ?

Comment: @KM6895, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHo, there it works without streaming but I have tested with Saxon 9.9 EE that it also works with streaming. I think you used the wrong value for the map's key.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinHonnen This was the missing line of code in my attempts after @Michael Kay's suggestion `<xsl:accumulator-rule match="Data/Row" select="()"/>`